# DSL query in Kibana Visualisation

Tags: elasticsearch, bigdata, visualization, kibana, dsl

Can I use my DSL query which I wrote in "DEV tool" option of Kibana for visualization? 
I'm currently writing queries which could be further used for visualization.

Comment: When you create a query, you can save it and then use it in your visualization.

Comment: @Val Thank you for responding. I'm currently on kibana 5.2.2.
There is no such method of saving the query

Comment: In the discover view, you can use your DSL query in the input box and then save your search.

Comment: Dear @Val, I've created my query in dev tools and it executed well, but I cant use it on discover as it shown error loading data. Please kindly check out my thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65271880/query-return-parsing-exception-size-query-malformed-no-start-object-after-q?noredirect=1#comment115394485_65271880