# query return [parsing_exception] [size] query malformed, no start_object after query name, with { line=1 & col=264 }

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dsl

I'm new in elasticsearch, and i try to use dev tools to create filters.
here is what work and I want to use

```
POST /transform_alldomain/_search
{
  "size":0,
    "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Email.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "bln.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "extract_date.max": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}}
```

now i want to use this similiar stuff to filter as type this into filter, edit as query dsl

```
{
  "size":0,
    "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "Email.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "bln.keyword"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "extract_date.max": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}}
```

it returns

```
[parsing_exception] [size] query malformed, no start_object after query name, with { line=1 & col=324 }
```

I don't know what is the difference and how to make it work

I need to create searched object from this

How I execute the filter:

[image]

it returns

[image]

Comment: both the queries that you gave in the question are exactly similar. By running which query are you getting the error?

Comment: dear @ESCoder, I've added how I execute it and how it returns. Yes both are the same

Comment: I'm really new with this kind of query, please kindly instruct me with this. My target is to create saved search.

Comment: You cannot use aggregations in the Edit Filter panel. That panel is only meant for queries not aggregations. Aggregations can be made with the Visualization app not the Discover app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Discover app is not the right tool to use to make aggregations, the Discover app is only useful for queries and filters.

What you want to achieve can be done with a Data table visualization. So instead of Discover, go to Visualize, then pick "Create Visualization"

[image: Create Visualization]

Then pick the "Data Table" Visualization

[image: Data Table]

Then pick your index pattern

[image: Index pattern]

And finally you can define your two `terms` aggregations like this:

[image: Terms aggregations]

Comment: Dear @Val thank you so much for the answer and explanation, but it want it to be visualized by other visualize app such as barchart or pie thats why I try to create saved search or index from it, since data table is a visualization and the data shown can't be used to create pie chart etc . Or do you have any workaround?

Comment: In your query above there's no query of filter part (i.e.), only aggregations, so there's nothing you can save in Discover  (i.e. no saved search). I suggested Data Table because I thought you wanted to see a similar result as in Discover (i.e. rows). But you're free to pick any other visualization that supports `terms` aggregations, such as Bar chart, Pie chart, etc. Try them out

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation @Val, but  I still dont understand how to get my target. my target is to remove duplicate based on descending timestamp using tophits1. On pie I didnot see any thing that can do it.

Comment: Well, your question doesn't mention your exact use case (remove duplicates) :-)

Comment: please pardon me for that.  I've tested the code on dev tools, it returning some result, can I create saved search from above code from dev tools?

Comment: As I just explained, no you can't because it's not a query, it's just some aggregations and a saved search is about query hits (i.e. documents), not aggregations. Your query is implicitly `"match_all": {}`, so there's no query to save. However, I'm sure the data table is the visualization you need to achieve what you want.

Comment: dear Val, thank you so much for your explanation, seems like I have to create another workaround. Please kindly help me by check out in this thread @Val : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65246803/kibana-tophits-on-transform-group-by-a-field-not-all-field. I'm so blind in elastic. Thank you